# How to approach a project naming activity for Junior Prom?

Tags: planning

I've been given a school project where I have to come up with a name for our junior prom. I already made some up like "rendezvous under the stars," but I can't think of anything else. How should I approach this project?

Answer (score 1):

This is loosely about PM, not 100% off topic.  Part of major projects where some serious material organization transformations take place, PMs would deploy a concept called Organization Change Management.  This focus is all about preparing the organization to change so that resistance to such change is minimal.

One of the critical success factors is stakeholder participation, meaning the change is more likely to be accepted and enabled if key stakeholders had something to do with the change, even if only a little.

With your project, the theme or name of it needs to resonate with your stakeholders, including students, teachers, and likely parents.  So your problem is not a lack of imagination on your part but the method you are using to generate ideas and then to narrow it down to the chosen one.  This is NOT a solo event, not if you want the name to resonate and be accepted.

So what you need to do is come up with some ideas of how to get stakeholder involvement.  Focus groups?  Surveys?  A friendly competition?  All of these?  What you want to do is derive a method of name identification, testing across a representative sample of your stakeholder population, and then choosing.  Implement that and the name will be the result and will likely be accepted by majority of your stakeholders.